# Filtering Mapped React Table Data with JSON Data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I successfully mapped JSON inventory data into a React Table. My goal is to use buttons to filter this table and render the table results based on the filter conditions. How do I do this?

`Button Filters` Component:

```html
import React from 'react'
import Button from './Button'

const Form = ({reqType, setReqType, color, setColor, handleColorChange}) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e)=> e.preventDefault()}>

            <Button
            buttonText="Red"
            >
              </Button>
            <Button
            buttonText="White"
           />
          

    </form>
  )
}

export default Form
```

`Table` Component:

```html
import React from 'react'
import Row from './Row'
 
const Table = ({ wines }) => {
  return (
        <table >
            <tbody >
            {wines.map((wine, key) =>(
                    <Row wine={wine} key={key}/>
                ))}

            </tbody>
        </table>
  )
}

export default Table
```

`Row` Component:

```html
import React from 'react'
import Cell from './Cell'

const Row = ({ wine }) => {
  return (
   <tr>
       {Object.entries(wine).map(([key, value]) => {
           return (
               <Cell key={key} cellData={JSON.stringify(value)}/>
           )

        } ) }
   </tr>
  )
}

export default Row
```

`Cell` Component:

```html
import React from 'react'

const Cell = ({cellData,wine}) => {
  return (
    <td >
     {cellData}
    </td>
  )
}

export default Cell
```

`App` Component:

```html
<Form 
  reqType={reqType} 
  setReqType={setReqType}
  color={color}
  setColor={setColor}
  handleColorChange={handleColorChange}/>
  <Table wines={wines}/>
```

Comment: Have states for both the full data, and the filtered data in `App`. When your `handleColorChange` handler is called `filter` out only that data that matches the colour, update the state, and pass that filtered data down to the table.

Comment: @Andy excuse me as I am a beginner, but, how do I pass the filtered data down to the table?

Comment: I've pared down your (very good) code to a [mcve] using state and added that as an answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Andy ok, this makes a lot of sense, thank you for taking the time to do this! I do have one more question if you don't mind. The json data I am using is formatted weird, it doesn't identify the inventory as red, white, dry, etc. Using filter, I am thinking of using something with "including" so that when "red is selected, the wine titles with "pinot noir" or "cabernet" will show up in filtered results. Is this possible?  the data is formatted like, (example):                                                               {"key":"29978045","field2":"Dark Horse Pinot Noir","field3":") etc

Comment: I would probably maintain an object like `{ red: ['pinot noir', 'cabernet'], white: [...]}` and then check wine names against those two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned that you need a state for the filtered data. You don't. But you do need two - one to hold the full data set, and another to maintain the colour. You can then use a function to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out objects based on their colour.

So I've played around with your code, removed a bunch of things to make this example readable, added a `Button` component, added a reset button, and added a basic dataset.

Hopefully you can see how it all fits together.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// We passing in the data - you may not being doing this
// your list of wines may come from an API call, but I'm
// keeping this simple
function Example({ data }) {

  // Set the wines state to the passed in data,
  // and initialise the color state (to undefined)
  const [ wines, setWines ] = useState(data);
  const [ color, setColor ] = useState();

  // Simple function to accept a color
  // as an argument and update the state with it
  function handleColor(color) {
    setColor(color);
  }

  // If color is undefined return all the wines!
  // Otherwise `filter` the wines based on their colour
  function filterData(wines, color) {
    if (!color) return wines;
    return wines.filter(wine => wine.color === color);
  }

  // Pass down the handleColor function in the Form props,
  // and call `filteredData` to have an updated list of wines
  // that you pass as a props to the table
  return (
    <div>
      <Form handleColor={handleColor} />
      <Table wines={filterData(wines, color)} />
    </div>
  );

}

// Pass in the `handleColor` function
function Form({ handleColor }) {
  
  // Buttons get their own `handleClick` function
  // which extracts the colour from the button's dataset
  // and then calls `handleColor` with that color
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { color } = e.target.dataset;
    handleColor(color);
  }
  
  // Button components get text, color,
  // and the `handleClick` function as props
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        text="Red"
        color="red"
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
      <Button
        text="White"
        color="white"
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
      <Button
        text="Reset"
        color=""
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );

}

function Button({ text, color, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <button
      data-color={color}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >{text}</button>
  );
}

function Table({ wines }) {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {wines.map(wine => (
          <Row wine={wine} key={wine.id}/>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function Row({ wine }) {
  return (
   <tr>
     {Object.entries(wine).map(([key, value]) => {
       return <Cell key={value} value={value} />;
     })}
   </tr>
  )
}

function Cell({ value }) {
  return <td>{value}</td>;
}

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Plonk', color: 'red' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rose', color: 'red' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Vanilla', color: 'white' },
  { id: 4, name: 'White', color: 'white' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Plonk', color: 'red' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Steve', color: 'white' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
button { margin-right: 0.2em; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #676767; margin-top: 1em; }
table td { padding: 0.4em; border: 1px solid #efefef; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```